# Show tab bar on modal View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

On click button "Go!" show white View Controller.
 
I want show tabbar on white ViewController, but it doesn't show. How i make this correctly? Swift please, thanks.

[image: storyboard screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in firstView,so the firstViewController embed in NavigationController,then make a push segue,the tabBar will not dismiss.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use navigation controller to see tab bar. by presenting modally you can't get tab bar in white controller.

Swift code:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: In Go button action method. make sure that you have put correct storyboard id in interface builder (White view controller).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong segue just delete old segue and add new segue this way by pressing control key[image]:

Comment: Do like this but tabbar not visible(

Comment: Read this tutorial for more info: http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/

Comment: Follow the tutorial I suggest you it will help you.